# Use of linux timerfd for implementing timeouts in Dev poll reactor

Tags: c++, timer, epoll, ace, reactor

Was just wondering whether use of timerfd (timerfd_create) for linux would give any performance benefit over Timer_Heap or Timer_Wheel. 
Surely, this is a very high level question and the only place I have seen it being used in any framework is "muduo".Also, I don't have any performance comparisons as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event-loop libraries like libevent, maintain the timers in a min-heap and pass the timeout till the next timer expiry to `select`/`epoll`. Note that adding and removing a timer does not involve any system calls in this scenario, it just adds a new element into the min-heap.

When you use `timerfd`, it takes 3 system calls (`timerfd_create()`, `timerfd_settime()` and `epoll_ctl()`) just to create a timer. And every time it expires you need to `read()` from that file descriptor.

`timerfd` could be useful for applications without an event loop, but for ones that already use a decent event loop it is pretty much useless.

Comment: The muduo framework does use an event loop, but then I am not sure if its being used as a standard networking framework. But for now, I will take your word that timerfd is pretty useless for epoll/select etc.